# Encoding in email send using Velocity template

Tags: spring, encoding, character-encoding, velocity

I am sending email using velocity template in Rusian language, the mail receiving with junk character.

The mail template.

```
 <html>
<body>
<h3>Dear ${name},
    <br/>Greetings from ${companyName}.</h3>

<span>Your Subscription will expire on : ${expiryDate}</span><br/>
<span>Нажмите <a href=${homePageUrl}>здесь</a>, чтобы войти.</span><br/>
<span>Click <a href=${homePageUrl}>here</a> to login.</span><br/>
<h3>Regards, <br/>
    ${companyName}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

The receiving mail:-

> > Dear Deepesh,  Greetings from ..... Your Subscription will expire on : 23-04-2029 Ru ??????? ?????, ?????
> >     ?????. Click here to login. Regards,  Budbeed Learning

The Russian part is junk.

Now my email send code.

```
SendEmailResponse response = null;
    try {
        VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
        final Map<String, String> contextMap = request.getContextMap();
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : contextMap.entrySet()) {
            velocityContext.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        velocityEngine.mergeTemplate("/templates/" + contextMap.get("templateName"),"UTF-8", velocityContext, stringWriter);

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
        mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(KP_DEV_MAIL_RU);
        mimeMessageHelper.setTo(contextMap.get("email"));
        mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(contextMap.get("subject"));
        mimeMessageHelper.setText(stringWriter.toString(), true);

    /*FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File("banner.jpg"));
    mimeMessageHelper.addInline("banner", file);

    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(new File("Attachment.jpg"));
    mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment("Attachment.jpg", fileSystemResource);*/

        InputStreamSource source = new ByteArrayResource(request.getFile().toByteArray());
        mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment("Invoice.pdf", source );
        if(LMSCommonUtils.matchEmail(contextMap.get("email"))) {
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while sending invoice",e);
        res
    }
```

Comment: Please tell us how you initialized your velocity engine. Especially, did you set `input.encoding = UTF8`?

Comment: Hi,, @Autowired
    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe javamailsender also should configure `UTF8` . Try like below

```
javaMailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hi, chaning in the Main java file.  JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");